# PHP Class - return a row ID in the __construct and always reference that

Tags: php, class, oop

Trying to get my head around using classes and using it as an object.

Im am converting a number of functions to use one single class. This class is for customers.

What I want to do is create the new customer object:

```
$customer = new Customer($customer_info);
```

My class currently looks:

```
class Customer {

  private $customer_info;
  private $mysqli;

  function __construct(Array $customer_info, Mysqli $mysqli) {
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    $this->customer_info = $customer_info;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE id = 33");
    $customerArray = array();
    while ($customer = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $customerArray[] = array(
            'id' => $customer->id,
            'first_name' => $customer->first_name,
            'last_name' => $customer->last_name,
            'email' => $customer->email
        );
    }
    $customer_ID = $customerArray->id;
    //return var_dump($customerArray);
  }

  function getCustomerId() {
    return "id:$customer_ID";
  }

}
```

When I create a new customer object, I am passing in the information and then I want to either insert a row or update a current one with the new customer information array thats passed in.

That is fine, I have done that else where in another function.

However, after this I want to be able to use a number of functions on that object.

So example:

```
$customer = new Customer($customer_info); // create / update
$customer = customer->getCustomerID();
```

I would like that getCustomerID function to simply return the ID of the database row that was created / updated when the new object was initiated. In my class currently you can see how I tried to set a value and then use that in the function... but im sure thats not how it works.

I have used Laravel and want it to work similar to the way the classes work there.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "return the ID of the current object"?

Comment: So using Laravel as the example, you can do $user = User::find(1); $user-delete(); That delete function, you dont have to pass in the row ID, the object just knows its to do with that row you have found...

Comment: So your "Customer" class could have more than one Customer object inside? So proper name should be CustomerRepository or CustomerCollection, or something like this. Am I wrong?

Comment: Just a note on your design, constructors really shouldn't be doing any real work.  All they should do is initialise the object to a valid default state.

Comment: It will only every be referencing / creating / affecting one row. if thats what you mean?

Comment: @GordonM Okay I thought that might be something too, should I create a function e.g. "checkForUser()" and do `$customer = new Customer(); $customer->checkForUser; $customer->getCustomerID;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create Class variables

```
    class Customer {

  private $customer_info;
  private $mysqli;
 public  $customer_ID;

  function __construct(Array $customer_info, Mysqli $mysqli) {
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    $this->customer_info = $customer_info;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE id = 33");
    $customerArray = array();
    while ($customer = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $customerArray[] = array(
            'id' => $customer->id,
            'first_name' => $customer->first_name,
            'last_name' => $customer->last_name,
            'email' => $customer->email
        );
    }
    $this->customer_ID = $customerArray->id;
    //return var_dump($customerArray);
  }

  function getCustomerId() {
    return $this->customer_ID;
  }

}
```

Comment: This is literally what I have just done :) Now I have my head around it, everything is all good. Thanks for the reply.